# Add jQuery to elements in an array at set interval of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I would like to animate to clear out a list of items at slightly different times, say in 20ms intervals. (Think of Android 4.2 alert screen when you clear messages).

However, I can't figure out how to `addClass` to different elements in an array at interval time. I've tried this, but this just applies the jQuery to the last element:

```
for item in App.itemsController.content
  jQuery('#box').delay(2000).queue (n) ->
    selector = '.' + item.objectId
    console.log selector
    $(selector).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig')
```

I've also tried `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` to no avail.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a closure to keep a reference to the item variable.  I don't use CoffeeScript but in javascript I would do this.

```
var box = jQuery('#box');
for (var i in App.itemsController.content) {
    var item = App.itemsController.content[i];
    (function(item) {
        box.delay(2000).queue(function() {
            var selector = '.' + item.objectId;
            $(selector).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig');
        });
    }(item));
}
```

Maybe this is how you do it in CoffeeScript?  Just had a quick look at the syntax.

```
for item in App.itemsController.content
  do (item) ->
     jQuery('#box').delay(2000).queue (n) ->
       selector = '.' + item.objectId
       console.log selector
       $(selector).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig')
```

You should also make a reference to the #box element outside the loop, otherwise your program has to search the DOM on every iteration.

Comment: Your JavaScript looks right but not your CoffeeScript; `(item) -> ...` just defines a function, but doesn't call it. You'd want to use `do` in CoffeeScript: `do (item) ->`. See the bottom of [this section](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) for details on `do`.

Comment: That looks better. The for-function construct is common enough that CoffeeScript has `do` specifically for this use case.